How to add input field on button click
I'm trying to add field on Button Click but by default field is not showing and not adding on button click
i've tried my best but i don't know what is the problem i added functions and use Math for generate unique id console.log is is working perfectly nut fields are not showing
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";

const DynamicForm = () => {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState([]);

  const addField = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newFieldId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    fields.push(...fields, { label: "", type: "text", id: newFieldId });
    console.log(fields);
  };

  const handleFieldChange = (index, event) => {
    const updatedFields = [...fields];
    updatedFields[index].label = event.target.value;
    setFields(updatedFields);
  };

  const handleTypeChange = (index, event) => {
    const updatedFields = [...fields];
    updatedFields[index].type = event.target.value;
    setFields(updatedFields);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <h2>Dynamic Form</h2>
        {fields.map((field, index) => (
          <div key={field.id}>
            <label htmlFor={field.id}>Label: </label>
            <input
              id={field.id}
              name={field.id}
              value={field.label}
              onChange={(e) => handleFieldChange(index, e)}
            />
            <select
              value={field.type}
              onChange={(e) => handleTypeChange(index, e)}
            >
              <option value="text">Text</option>
              <option value="email">Email</option>
            </select>
            <Button onClick={() => setFields(fields.slice(0, index))}>
              Remove
            </Button>
          </div>
        ))}
        <div className="gap-3">
          <Button onClick={addField}>Add Field</Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default DynamicForm;


Your addField function is directly changing fields, instead of using setFields function. Using the function tells react that a state is changed and the component should be updated. Here's what your function should look like:
  const addField = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newFieldId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    // using setFields function instead of directly changing the fields.
    setFields(prevData => [...prevData, { label: "", type: "text", id: newFieldId }]); 
  };


Seems to wrong usage of UseState hook.
const addField = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newFieldId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    setFields([...fields,{ label: "", type: "text", id: newFieldId }])
    // fields.push(...fields, { label: "", type: "text", id: newFieldId });
    // logging Fields here will not work because setFields is async in nature.
    // console.log(fields);
  };

